About the tangent to the Archimedean spiral
Good morning,
I recently discovered mathematical contents about (Archimedean) spiral and I find it fascinating.
Gauss Wantzel's theorem ensures that we can neither perform an angle trisection nor construct $\pi$ only with a ruler and a compass, but with this kind of spiral it becomes possible. I'm interested in $\pi$ construction here :

This is the spiral defined by the polar equation :
$$r = \frac{\theta}{2\pi}$$
I also drew the line defined by :
$$y = 2\pi x - 2 \pi$$
My question : Why is it tangent to the curve described by the spiral ?

My attempt :
I start by switching to Cartesian coordinates :
$$x = r \cos(\theta) = \frac{\theta}{2\pi}\cos(\theta)$$
$$y = r \sin(\theta) = \frac{\theta}{2\pi}\sin(\theta)$$
So we have :
\begin{align*}
    \frac{dx}{d\theta} &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\cos(\theta) - \frac{\theta}{2\pi}\sin(\theta) \\
    \frac{dy}{d\theta} &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(\theta) + \frac{\theta}{2\pi}\cos(\theta)
\end{align*}
Thus :
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(\theta) + \frac{\theta}{2\pi}\cos(\theta)}{\frac{1}{2\pi}\cos(\theta) - \frac{\theta}{2\pi}\sin(\theta)}$$
Consequently :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{\theta = 2\pi} = \frac{\frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(2\pi) + \frac{2\pi}{2\pi}\cos(2\pi)}{\frac{1}{2\pi}\cos(2\pi) - \frac{2\pi}{2\pi}\sin(2\pi)} = \frac{0 + 1 \cdot 1}{\frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot 1 - 1 \cdot 0} = 2\pi$$
So the slope of the tangent at $(1,0)$ is $2\pi$ and Y-intercept is at $-2\pi$, hence the result.

Is this right ?

Your attempt seems correct. The equation of the straight line is indeed a tangent to the spiral at that point.

As @M.Riyan said above, your calculation and the conclusion seem correct. However, I wonder how this drawing relates to 'constructing $\pi$'. As far as I know, 'drawing a tangent to a curve through a point on its arc' is not a primitive step in Euclidean constructions. So, while you have successfuly proven the correlation between the tangent and $\pi$, I still can't see how we can use the proven property to 'construct $\pi$ with the spiral'. :(

You may do not need the compass, but still need the spiral to be printed on the paper to perfectly draw a tangent at the point $\theta=2\pi$

Yes, we call it quadratix method as far as I know :( https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/quadratrice/quadratrice.shtml
